# Create new div element from scratch on mouseovering a text with DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to work on getting "a tooltip" on hovering a text.
This tooltip should be placed below the text. The tooltip should get its content from a database but I can handle that part, and styling it with css. Only problem here is that I can't create a new div element from scratch when mouseovering.

My current code uses existing div element but the code is supposed to create a new div element where place the code.

```
<script>
   function createTooltip(str)
   {
      if (str == "" || !str)
      {
         return;
      }

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else // code for IE5 and IE6
      {
         xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
         {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "tooltip.php?s="+str, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
   }

   function removeTooltip()
   {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
   }
   </script>
   <p><br>
   <a href="" rel="35" onmouseover="createTooltip(this.rel);" onmouseout="removeTooltip();">Test</a>
   <br><br>
   <div id="txtHint"></div></p>
```

The tooltip.php file has this content in it:

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['s']);
echo $q;
?>
```

For now it just prints the rel attribute in  function. Now what I really want it to do is to create completely new div with the xml response in it, instead of an existing div. So this tooltip should appear below the text, like with this existing div. In future I will make it a hover div element, so it just hovers on all content.

Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: You mention [jquery] in your tags, yet your code is plain vanilla JavaScript. Do you use jQuery? It could make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake, I'm very exhausted and tired after trying this for two hours or so. How this would be easier with jQuery? My experience in jQuery and JavaScript is basically nil.

Comment: I've posted my answer, give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.hover()` function to define both mouseover/mouseout events. You can use `.after()` to append new DIV and `.remove()` to remove it.

Assuming this is the element you hover over:

```
<a href="#" id="test" rel="35">Test</a>
```

This sample demonstrates the effect:

```
$('#test').hover(
    function() {
        var text = "Tooltip for rel: " + this.rel;
        $(this).after($("<div></div>").html(text).addClass("tooltip"));
    },

    function() {
        $(this).next().remove();
    }
)
```

And here's live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3LgWk/1/

Oh and jQuery makes AJAX calls a lot easier as well - give it a look when you get a chance.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for something exactly like this.
Much love to you <3

Comment: You're welcome :) Please check the answer as accepted if the solution was useful.